# Download from a redirect using wget or curl

Tags: linux, command-line, download, wget, curl

I want to download something from https://www.articy.com/en/downloads/server/. The link I have to click to download the file is https://www.articy.com/download/articyserver3.

I tried using `curl -OJL https://www.articy.com/download/articyserver3` and `wget -c --content-disposition https://www.articy.com/download/articyserver3`, but I'm not getting the exe I need.

I know this has been asked countless times, but I haven't been able to figure this one out. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The result I get is javascript, suggesting you need javascript to get the data, which neither curl or wget would support directly. The page mentions `https://www.articy.com/download/ad3/Setup_ArticyServer_Release_3.1.37.40510.exe` which is probably what you actually want

Comment: Yes, exactly. Actually I already downloaded the file and did what I needed with it, but I'm writing a detailed guide and having a simple command to download the file would be nice. Sure, I can wget to that direct link, and that's what I did to get the file into my Linux server, but if the version changes I'm not willing to always keep the guide up-to-date with the latest url.

Comment: In the guide, you'll just have to tell people to go that page and let JS do the rest. Either that, or convince the site owners to have a static permaurl that redirects to the latest exe

Comment: According to the [terms and conditions](https://www.articy.com/en/terms-conditions/) you are not allowed to distribute the software: "Such software may not be copied, adapted, translated, made available, distributed, modified, disassembled, decompiled, reverse engineered or combined with any other software". Absolutely proprietary. Why not simply link to the companies download page? That way you would avoid any involvement with their lawyers.

Comment: I'm not redistributing anything, @mashuptwice, I want to DOWNLOAD the file through command line. I think it's not hard to understand.

Answer (score -1):

Figured out a hacky way to achieve what I want:

```
wget $(curl https://www.articy.com/scripts/Redirector.php?articyserver3 | grep window.location.href | cut -d'"' -f2 | sed 's/\\//g')
```

Explanation:
Since the URL I want is inside the page's `<script>` tag, I used a combination of `grep`, `cut` and `sed` to process the output of `curl` until I got the URL I want to download.